# Mysql date time , add hours

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check how much time left by the user in the particular order.
In our company's we have a shift timings 9:00 hrs to 16:00 hrs.. so every user have 4 office hours(9:00 to 16:00 hrs) to respond.
Ex. If the client made an order at 15:00:00  a user get 4 hours 1 hour today and 3 hours tomorrow, I want to calculate how much time he left to respond.

Max 4 office hours
Order date time 17-May-2017 15:00:00 pm 
He has 1 hour of today and 3 hours tomorrow
I want to calculate time how much he left. In my SQL

Comment: That does not sound like a request to be solved solely by the database. Just put your logic into PHP, thats more simple and flexible

Comment: So please guide me the login in php i am confused

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an order table with a request_time datetime field (it really helps if you share details like that with us), the latest response time for the order is:

```
case
    when time(request_time) <= '09:00:00'
    then date(request_time) + interval 13 hour
    when time(request_time) >= '16:00:00'
    then date(request_time) + interval 1 day + interval 13 hour
    when time(request_time) >= '12:00:00'
    then request_time + interval 1 day - interval 3 hour
    else request_time + interval 4 hour
end
```